# La formule « remonte là-haut » est-elle un pléonasme ?

Tags: usage, stylistique

Je sais que la tournure « monter en haut » [est considérée pléonastique](https://www.lefigaro.fr/langue-francaise/expressions-francaises/2017/09/07/37003-20170907ARTFIG00002-10-pleonasmes-a-bannir-sur-le-champ.php).

Mais, peut-on dire que la formule « remonte là-haut » constitue un pléonasme aussi ?

Par exemple :

> La semaine, il sauve « les gens » de cette espèce en perdition et le
> dimanche soir il **remonte là-haut** voir si j’y suis. ([Source](http://www.cave-poesie.com/la-piste-de-lutopiste/)).

Comment: Comme tu veux. Ça dépend. De toute façon, même si c'est un pléonasme, tu peux bien l'utiliser, on comprendra ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contrairement à ce qu'affirment de nombreuses sources ***monter là-haut*** ou ***monter en haut*** ne sont pas de vrais pléonasmes.

Ce qui peut être considéré comme un pléonasme c'est *monter **vers** le haut* car monter implique cette direction.

En revanche, ***en haut*** ou ***là-haut*** précisent une destination que ***monter*** seul n'implique pas. On peut très bien monter sans avoir l'intention d'arriver ***jusqu'en haut**, **jusque là-haut***.

On peut bien sûr quand même dire simplement ***Je monte*** si le contexte suffit à comprendre où on se rend ou si la destination n'a simplement pas besoin d'être précisée.

Il en va de même pour ***remonter là-haut***.

D'autre part, dans la phrase citée dans la question, on trouve il me semble une variation de l'expression *Il va voir **là-bas** si j'y suis* que l'on percevrait moins s'il était seulement écrit *il remonte (à la montagne) voir si j'y suis*.

Answer (score 4):

Dans *il remonte là-haut*, je crois voir un possible renvoi à un élément du contexte qui préciserait ce *là-haut*, ce qui réduit pour moi l'effet de "pléonasme". Il pourrait s'agir d'un village sur une montagne où l'auteur se trouve, où d'un étage dans un immeuble, ou bien d'un autre endroit plus élevé que celui où se déroule l'action, mais cet endroit n'est pas forcément *évident* dans le verbe *monter* seul.